# Как определить название устройства в UWP?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

Как определить и вывести в текстбокс название устройства? Вроде: "Lumia 950"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эту инфу можно вытащить из класса `EasClientDeviceInformation`

```
EasClientDeviceInformation eas = new EasClientDeviceInformation();
var deviceManufacturer = eas.SystemManufacturer;
var deviceModel = eas.SystemProductName;
```